# Error CS1525: Invalid Expression term ")"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

new to programming and I'm currently following a certain tutorial.
I've followed the code and copied it from the video itself (wrote it by hand), however, unity gives me the issue in the title.
Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private GameInput gameInput;

    private bool isWalking;

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 inputVector = gameInput.GetMovementVectorNormalized();

        Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);

        float moveDistance = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        float playerRadius = .7f;
        float playerHeight = 2f;

        bool canMove = !Physics.CapsuleCast(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.up * playerHeight, playerRadius, moveDir, moveDistance);

        if (!canMove)
        {
            Vector3 moveDirX = new Vector3(moveDir.x, 0, 0).normalized;
            canMove = !Physics.CapsuleCast(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.up * playerHeight, playerRadius, moveDirX, moveDistance);

            if (canMove)
            {
                moveDir = moveDirX;
            }

            else
            {
                Vector3 moveDirZ = new Vector3(0, 0, moveDir.z,).normalized;
                canMove = !Physics.CapsuleCast(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.up * playerHeight, playerRadius, moveDirZ, moveDistance);

                if (canMove)
                {
                    moveDir = moveDirZ;
                }
                else
                {
                    //cannot move
                }
            }
        }
        if (canMove)
        {
            transform.position += moveDir * moveDistance;
        }


        isWalking = moveDir != Vector3.zero;



        float rotateSpeed = 10f;
        transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);

    }

    public bool IsWalking()
    {
        return isWalking;
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the problem should be a missing character or an extra one. I found the number of ( and ) brackets to be matching. Where could the issue be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 36 - there is a comma followed by closing bracket:

```
moveDir.z,).normalized;
```

it's a redundant comma or there should be some variable after it

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on this line
Vector3 moveDirZ = new Vector3(0, 0, moveDir.z,).normalized;

It should be
Vector3 moveDirZ = new Vector3(0, 0, moveDir.z).normalized;

Unity is perfectly saying what is happening, be aware that you need to copy perfectly the code before asking a question.

If you are new to programming, this is a daily issue and you need to understand what is happening before asking for help.